# How to verify OTP in Java using simple loop?

Tags: java, verification, one-time-password

I'm a Java beginner and my project consists of creating a simple program to register users for an alumni center. The process creates an ID and then provides the new user with an *OTP*. Next is the login (Enter ID:, Enter OTP: ).

My *OTP* verification method is not working. It seems to be a problem with the IF.equals declaration, the process jumps straight to the ELSE condition.

Any suggestions why?

Here is my code:

```
class Main {
    static NewRegandLogin newRegAndLogin = new NewRegandLogin(null, null, null, null, null, null);
    static ArrayList<NewRegandLogin> loginInformation = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("        WELCOME TO THE ALUMNI SHE-CODES SYSTEM        ");
        System.out.println("_________________________________\n   - New Alumni registration - \n");
        System.out.println("");
        newRegAndLogin.registerNewGrad();
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("_________________________________");
        System.out.println();   
        System.out.println("Your new Alumni ID is: "  + newRegAndLogin.getAlumniId());
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your temporary password is:");
        System.out.println(newRegAndLogin.oTp(8));
        loginInformation.add(newRegAndLogin);
        System.out.println("_________________________________");
        System.out.println("_________________________________\n   - Alumni Login - \n");
        System.out.println("");
        newRegAndLogin.login();
        System.out.println(""); 
        System.out.println("Please make a list of completed Courses: -->Enter 'S' to stop adding courses<--");
        newRegAndLogin.setAlumniCourses();
        System.out.println("_________________________________");
        newRegAndLogin.setLinkedInPage();
        loginInformation.add(newRegAndLogin);
        //printAlumniProfile();
        System.out.println("_________________________________");
        newRegAndLogin.jobOffer();
        }
```

```
void login() {
    System.out.print("ID: ");
    alumniIdImput = scanner.nextLine();
    idVerification();
    do {
        System.out.println("Password (OTP if logging in for the first time): ");
        passwordImput = scanner.nextLine();
        oTpFromImput = passwordImput.toCharArray();
        oTpVerification();
    } while (isPasswordCorrect=false);

void oTpVerification() {
    isPasswordCorrect = false;
    if (oTpFromImput.equals(oTp(8))) {
        isPasswordCorrect = true;
        System.out.println("Logging In.....");
    }else {
        isPasswordCorrect = false;
        System.out.println("Incorrect password.\nPlease enter valid password: 8 alpha numeric 
                               characters(Aa,123,@,#,$,%)");
    }   
}
```

This is the oTp method

```
char[] oTp (int length) {       
        String capitalChars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        String smallChars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        String numbers = "0123456789";
        String symbols = "!@#$%^&*_-=+/.?<>";
                
        String values = capitalChars + smallChars + numbers + symbols;
                
        Random oneTimePassword = new Random();
        char[] password = new char[length];
                
        for(int i = 0; i<length;i++) {
            password[i] = values.charAt(oneTimePassword.nextInt(values.length()));
        }
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: `oTpFromImput.equals(oTp(8))` what does `oTp(8)` return?

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question, don't use comments for long pieces of code.

Comment: you are right please look updated code

Comment: If you're trying equals, you should try Array.equals(arr1, arr2)

Comment: `isPasswordCorrect=false` should be `isPasswordCorrect == false` or (better) `!isPasswordCorrect`.  The `=` operator is **assignment**.

Comment: when changing to `!isPasswordCorrect` there is a syntax error:  assert expected before this token

Answer (score 1):

It seems you built a guessing game, not an OTP verification code.

You first read the OTP from user, and only then randomly generate one to copare to it.

Basically, you code expects the user to guess a random 8 character password that has not been created you, which is basically impossible...

You need to generate to OTP first, show it to the user, then ask them to input it.

Comment: the oTp is generated previously in the Main class beforhand. are you saying that by comparing the user imput with a new oTp command I'm generating a new oTp instead of using the original one?

Comment: @GeriGlazer your `oTp` function generates a new OTP every time you run it. When you call it inside `equals` you run it, it creates new random numbers and returns new OTP array that will be different from the previous one.

Comment: Oooo! so, what you propose to do instead if trying to compare the user imput can't be equal to an oTp method?

Comment: [link] (https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-save-console-output-to-String-Java). Can this help me?

Comment: @GeriGlazer just store the result of the `oTp` function in a local or instance variable, and use that veriable to both print and check. You have a simple school exersize, not a production program requiring real IPC. Generate the OTP one time at the start of `main` and use the saved value.

Answer (score 0):

I see your logic code is generate OTP code after User input. It seem so wierd bro.

Whenever you call `oTp(8)` function will generate new OTP.

Use should generate OTP first then store somewhere, then User input and compare it.

Comment: there is an otp generator before the login.

Comment: Method `oTp(8)` is generate new OTP and it calling by `oTpVerification()`. But `oTpVerification()` called after User input. So how OTP generator before the login?

Comment: becouse the user gets an automatic ID and OTP after inserting name in the registerNewGrad() method.

Comment: If it have generate OTP before login. You have to store in somewhere then use it in if clause to compare user input. As i see in `if (oTpFromImput.equals(oTp(8)))` it always compare user input with new opt generate from `oTp(8)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the generated otp somewhere. Then compare it with the input otp. Right now you are comparing it with the otp(8). And otp(8) always returns a new otp.

Comment: I've tryed to store it in a String but did'nt work becouse the method is built in a different class and called in Main using an object from the same class. `Syso(newRegAndLogin.oTp(8));`

Comment: I can suggest some better ways but you need add some more code here

Comment: Thanks, I've edited and added the Main class for you all to see.